# laravel 4 - How to load different layout for a particular method?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have something like this :

```
class AController extends BaseController
{
  protected $layout = "templates.layouts.master";
  protected $data = "something";

  public function alt()
  {
    // this is wrong
    // i want to override "templates.layouts.master"
    // missing something obviously here
    $this->layout = ??? what should do?
    $this->layout->content = View::make("content", $this->data);
  }
}
```

In method alt, I wish to use different layout than the default "templates.layouts.master".

I have very limited laravel 4 knowledge. This maybe something easy to achieve, but is beyond my knowledge.

Possible solutions that I forsee:

1. define a construct method, and detect what is the current method, and set a different value for $layout (However, I not sure how to get the current method name).
2. do an assignment like what I put in above.

Which is the correct way?

Comment: Just overwrite the `layout` variable? `$this->layout = 'templates.layouts.custom';`

Comment: That's first come to my mind, but it seems right after construct, the layout is instantiated.

Comment: If it's only that method which has some custom rule, it makes sense for it to live inside the method, so when you come to it in future, it's clear what's going on. If you want to load custom templates for every new method it might be worth looking into something on construct, but it seems overkill for if it's just that method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the layout to be another view per method:

```
class AController extends BaseController
{
    protected $layout = "templates.layouts.master";
    protected $data = "something";

    public function alt()
    {
        $this->layout = View::make('templates.layouts.alt');
        $this->layout->content = View::make("content", $this->data);
    }
}
```

If you check out the `BaseController`, you'll see that all it does is call [View::make()](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/controllers/BaseController.php#L14) to set the layout view. You can do the same to over-ride its default.

Answer (score 1):

OK, solution 1 seems to be possible, but I think is fugly :

```
class AController extends BaseController
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    if (Request::is("..."))
    {
        $this->layout = "alternative layout";
    }
  }
}
```